# Am I interpreting も correctly in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> 有名な「ファミリア」は人員**も**豊富で基本的に飽和しているところが多い。

I'm interpreting this part as: *Many Familias **also** have an abundance of members*

But I'm not sure if the も here is actually inclusive.

Here's a picture of the page.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **有名な**「ファミリア」は人員も豊富で・・・

**Famous** Familias have abundant human resources...

If a Familia is famous, it already has a lot of staff, too.

例文:

> **美味しい**ものは、体に**も**いい。
>   **不細工な**女は、性格**も**悪い。
>   **充実した日々を過ごしてる**ヤツは、笑顔**も**輝いてる。